# Will every version of Vulkan run on every GPU (PC)?

Tags: vulkan

If app/game is made with Vulkan 1.X (X is minor version of API), will it work on every GPU. For example if program is written with Vulkan 1.3 (the most recent one), does every GPU have drivers with support for this version, or older GPUs don't have it and program will not run on them. If the latter is true, is it best to use Vulkan 1.0 and branch for every feature that we want to use in app that is supported by hardware and API version?

Comment: That depends on whether the manufacturer provides a driver for it....

Answer (score 3):

Of course not. E.g. I think GCN1 and Fermi are already no longer supported.

It is best to use the feature set of the devices you target. Either your program needs recent high perf GPUs (and modern features), or not. You are asking us something only you can know.

Comment: I am not asking something that only I can now because i want my game/program to be universal and run for all that want to use it regardless of their hardware. Of course i won't be expecting app to run on old GPU.

Comment: if you want it to be universal, then you'll have to draw everything in software on cpu

Comment: @zix527 Which GPU do you consider sufficiently "old GPU"?

Comment: @krOoze that is actually good question that i didn't know i don't have answer to. After your answer I decided to use version that is supported by hardware on which program is launched, and if given version and hardware supports feature/extension that program might use, it will enable it.

Comment: @zix527 Right. To paraphraze Sun Tzu: He who supports all hardware, supports no hardware. Problem is that even by using vanilla Vulkan 1.0, you are cutting someone off. Notably, perfectly good usable Intel CPUs have iGPUs that don't support Vulkan at all.

Comment: @zix527 If you are uberhardcore about supporting everything at all cost, that is something web browsers try to deal with. You might want to investigate SwiftShader or some such technology. Alternatively, it is also possible you are working at the wrong abstraction level. It is possible you should be using some high-level productivity framework, while that middleware deals with hardware for you for the most part.